# prove these properties of the orthogonal projection

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

let $F$ be a closed vector subspace of $E$ a real Hilbert space 
and $P_F : E\to F$ be the orthogonal projection onto $F$

then :

1. $\text{Ker}(P_F) = F^\perp$ and $\text{Im}(P_F) = F$
2. $P_F$ is a contraction mapping
3. $\langle P_F(x),y\rangle = \langle x,P_F(y)\rangle\;\; \forall x,y \in E$
4. $P_F  ∘ P_F = P_F $

fourth property is easy to prove since $P_F$ maps onto $F$ it means it's an element of $F$ then its orthogonal projection onto $F$ is itself

for the second property since $P_F$ is linear and bounded then for every $x,y \in E$ 
$$||P_F(x)-P_F(y)|| = ||P_F(x-y)|| \leq ||x-y||$$
therefore it's a contraction mapping

let $x,y \in E$

\begin{align}
\langle x-P_F(x),z \rangle = 0\;\; \forall z \in F \\
\langle y-P_F(y),z \rangle = 0\;\; \forall z \in F \\
\end{align}
since both $P_F(x)$ & $P_F(y)$ belongs to $F$ then 
\begin{align}
\langle x-P_F(x),P_F(y)\rangle = 0 \\
\langle y-P_F(y),P_F(x)\rangle = 0 \\
\end{align}
since the inner product is linear in the first slot 
\begin{align}
\langle x,P_F(y)\rangle = \langle P_F(x),P_F(y)\rangle \\
\langle y,P_F(x)\rangle = \langle P_F(y),P_F(x)\rangle \\
\end{align}
because $E$ is a real Hilbert space then the inner product is symmetric therefore property 3 is proved

I want two things :

- a confirmation that I've correctly shown those 3 properties
- a little push or some help concerning the first property because other than writing down the definition I still haven't figured out what to do next

thanks !

Comment: First I advice you to use `\langle` $\langle$ and `\rangle` $\rangle$ instead of `<` and `>` to denote the inner product [also see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47085). For your question: property 3 and 4 look correct to me - but property 2 does not. Why do you have $\Vert P_F(x-y)\Vert\leq\Vert x-y\Vert$ (that is exactly what you have to show)? You only know $\Vert P_F(x-y)\Vert\leq\Vert P_F\Vert\Vert x-y\Vert$ since $P_F$ is linear and bounded. For properties 1 and 2 it might help that $E=F\oplus F^\perp$ so every $x\in E$ can be written as $x=y+z$ with *unique* $y\in F,z\in F^\perp$

Comment: Your $||P_F(x-y)|| \leq ||x-y||$ defines Liptchitz but is it not necessary for a contraction to have $||P_F(x-y)|| \leq k||x-y||$ with $0\lt k\lt 1$? (for the identity you have $k=1$ but a lot of fixed points).